# Getting error in function pointer typecase in CPP

Tags: c++

I have following member funtion in class Regwrite.

```
unsigned int RegWrite::register_write(unsigned int reg_addr, unsigned int value) {
//Function definition
}
```

I want to assign the above funtion to a non-class funtion pointer.

```
unsigned int (*REG_WR_FUNC) (unsigned int addr, unsigned int val);

void register_write_access(REG_WR_FUNC wr_func) {
   g_wr_func = wr_func;
}
```

In another Regwrite member function, I have passed the register_write function.

```
unsigned int RegWrite::init() {
register_write_access(register_write);
}
```

I am getting below error in typecast, anyone help to resolve the error?

```
error: cannot convert 'unsigned int (RegWrite::*)(unsigned int, unsigned int) {aka unsigned int (RegWrite::*)(unsigned int, unsigned int)}' to 'REG_WR_FUNC {aka unsigned int (*)(unsigned int, unsigned int)}' for argument '1' to 'void customer_register_write_access(REG_WR_FUNC)'
```

Comment: You have to use [std::bind](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/functional/bind/)

Comment: Pointer to function and pointer to member function are two different beasts.

Comment: You can't do that. You need a free function, or a static member.

Comment: @Detonar `std::bind` does not produce a thing that's convertible to a function pointer.

Comment: @molbdnilo I used it several times to bind the `this` pointer to a member function. And if you change the signatures a bit you can use that.

Answer (score 0):

In order to call `register_write`, beside the function address, also `this` pointer must be provided.

So the member function actual takes a hidden pointer argument of the class type.

You must provided `this` pointer either at calling time or at binding time.

If `this` is provided at binding time, you may use `std::bind` to create a function object which stores both member function pointer and `this` pointer.

If `this` is accessible at calling time, use following notation:

```
// the function pointer must be a member function pointer.
unsigned int (RegWrite::*REG_WR_FUNC) (unsigned int addr, unsigned int val);

REG_WR_FUNC wr_func;
(this->*wr_func)(args...);
```

Comment: In my case REG_WR_FUNC can't be a member of RegWrite.

Comment: @Rajeshkumar then use `std::bind`

Comment: Note that lambdas are almost always preferred to `std::bind`.  e.g. `auto REG_WR_FUNC = [rw = std::make_shared<RegWrite>(&regWriteInst)](unsigned int addr, unsigned int val) { return rw->register_write(addr, val); }`  (Here I'm capturing a shared_ptr to make sure regWriteInst doesn't dangle; this can be simplified if you have strict control over the instance's lifetime.)